# Unable to find the position of a random date anywhere in the column headers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the position of a random date anywhere in the column headers. When I try to hardcode the range I can find it.

> Question: How can I track the position of the date without using hardcoded range?

This is how the date in the sheet looks like.

[image]

My current attempt:

```
Sub FindDate()
    Dim lcol&, cel As Range, specificCel As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'    lcol = ws.Rows(1).CurrentRegion.Columns.count
    
    For Each cel In ws.Range("A1:H1")
        If IsDate(cel) Then
            Set specificCel = cel
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cel
    
    MsgBox specificCel.Column
End Sub
```

Comment: What exact problem are you facing with your code?

Comment: I'm not facing any problem with the code. It works flawlessly. I wish to bring about a small change within the script so that I don't need to use this hardcoded range `Range("A1:H1")`.

Comment: Find the last column in the first row using `LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` and then use something like `For Each cel In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(1,LastCol))`

Comment: Yep, this is what I was after. Thanks a lot @Siddharth Rout.